# How to get Log of particular applicaion?

Tags: logging, ubuntu-16.04, infinite-loop, cpu-usage, event-log

When I start running application on Ubuntu 16.04, i have face a problem of CPU usage of 100% for each application for long time. I need to get log of that particular application (its execution log) so I can find problem/bug.